# How to create dynamic textfield , accessble and editable for each textfield in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Can anyone help me ? I want to create dynamic `text field` in side a loop.I have been able to create and made it editable too. My requirements are in below.
i.I want to access each `text fields` value and make a sum of those will store in a `Label`.
ii. Let's say there are 5 dynamic created text fields having value (10,20,30,40,50).
so label displays sum of 5 value.  ie. 10+20+30+40+50 = 150
if i make changes in either `textfield` values, it should recalculate and changes the total sum in `label`.
my logic goes as below.

-(void)create
{

```
    myarr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1000",@"2000",@"3000",@"4000",@"5000", nil];

int x = 20, y = 50;
int width = 280, height = 40;
for (int item=0; item<[myarr count]; item++)
{
    edit_txt = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    edit_txt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myarr objectAtIndex:item]];
    [edit_txt setTag:item+1];
    edit_txt.placeholder  = @"Click here to type";
    edit_txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    edit_txt.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    edit_txt.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    edit_txt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
    edit_txt.delegate = (id)self;
    [self.view addSubview:edit_txt];
    y += height;
}

tot_txt = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(edit_txt.frame.origin.x, edit_txt.frame.origin.y + height + 10, width , height)];
tot_txt.placeholder  = @"Total Value";
tot_txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
tot_txt.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
tot_txt.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
tot_txt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
tot_txt.delegate = (id)self;
[self.view addSubview:tot_txt];


save_btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[save_btn setFrame:CGRectMake(tot_txt.frame.origin.x, tot_txt.frame.origin.y + height + 10, width , height)];
[save_btn setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[save_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(save_click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[save_btn setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:save_btn];
CALayer *btnlayer = [save_btn layer];
[btnlayer setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
[btnlayer setBorderWidth:0.3];
[btnlayer setCornerRadius:20.0];
```

}

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

{
    int count = 0;

```
for (int item = 0; item < [myarr count]; item++)
{
    UITextField *textField = ([[self.view viewWithTag:item + 1] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])?(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:item + 1]:nil;
    count += [textField.text intValue];
}
tot_txt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
```

}

Thanks in advance.
Ajeet Kumar.

Comment: Have you tried something ? Or like a code or something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more easy,

To access each text field (the scope is available only within the loop),you can use `tag` property of the text field.

**Example:**

```
for (int itemIndex = 1; itemIndex <= 5; itemIndex++)
{
      UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];

      //all properties assigning here

      textField.tag = itemIndex; //assigning tag here(starts from 1).
      textField.delegate = self;
      [self.view addSubview: textField];
}
```

Now, here comes the calculation. Implement the `UITextField` delegates.

Write the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` in your .h file

```
@interface yourClassName : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

To calculate while end editing,

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField  
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int itemIndex = 1; itemIndex <= 5; itemIndex++)
    {
          UITextField *textField = ([[self.view viewWithTag:itemIndex] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])?(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:itemIndex]:nil;

          count += [textField.text intValue];
    }

    countLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
}
```

To calculate while editing, implement delegate `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` and use the same code base.

Also implement the delegates `textFieldShouldClear` , 
`textFieldShouldReturn` and use the same code base.

Please make sure that, your view not holding any elements with the tag from 1 to 5 except these test fields.

Also, you can avoid the looping by applying your thoughts on it ;)

Comment: This code should work, but instead of this line `UITextField *textField = ([[self.view viewWithTag:itemIndex + 1] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])?(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:itemIndex + 1]:nil;` it probably makes more sense to just stick those two lines in a "isKindOfClass" if conditional.

Comment: And actually, I didn't like the way you were using tags at first, but I just re-read the OP's question and since the textField's are in fact created dynamically, tags are a good way to go...

Comment: Also probably makes more sense for `for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < 5; itemIndex++)` to just start out with "itemIndex = 1; itemIndex <= 5" instead of adding 1 to itemIndex within the loop.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the pretty good suggestions. I don't like the 'if' conditions. That's why I wrote the conditional operator. I agree with your point ;)

Comment: Hi Ramshad. Thnx for your update. but no value is updating in my countLabel.text.

Comment: @AjeetKumarDalei Did you set your text fields' delegates? Oh, actually since they're created dynamically, you need to add this line upon creation: `textField.delegate = self;` and add `UITextFieldDelegate` to your class header.

Comment: @LyndseyScott:  Model, Actress And App Developer :O great and appreciable. I just watched your interview. really awesome one. Kudos.

Comment: @LyndseyScott: thanks to me, right (instead of AjeetKumarDalei)? lol,, u r most welcome.

Comment: Hi @Ramshad, @ Lyndsey Scott,  I am so pleased as u guys helps me a lot.The code is working for me. But as i have little knowledge on ios, so I arise this type of posts.

Comment: @Ramshad, Brother Can i have your skype id, so that i can freely ask you doubts .

Comment: @AjeetKumarDalei: shamsutk87

Comment: Yes brother @Ramshad, i have marked your answer. it is  working fine.
please do accept my skype request.

Answer (score 0):

I did like this,

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {

    UITableView* _tableView;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 768, 600) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SomeCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"SomeCell"];
        UITextField* _textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 600, 40)];
        _textField.delegate = self;
        _textField.tag = indexPath.row + 1;
        [_textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [_textField addTarget:self action:@selector(onTextChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:_textField];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)onTextChange:(id)sender
{

    double result = 0.0;
    for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < 5; itemIndex++) {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:itemIndex inSection:0]];
        UITextField* fooTF = (UITextField*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:itemIndex + 1];
        result += [fooTF.text doubleValue];
    }
    // update your lable here
    NSLog(@"result %f", result);
    //for sample
    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", result];
}
- (float)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

    return 50.0;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)string
{
    NSNumberFormatter* nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [nf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];

    NSString* newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", textField.text, string];
    NSNumber* number = [nf numberFromString:newString];

    //allow only numbers
    if (number)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```